# Create dynamic elements in javascript and visualize it on UI as soon as the node is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on a script that creates a tree. The problem i am facing is when large chunk of data comes it gets stuck for some time then rendering every thing at the end.

What i am looking for is can there be a way that make it more interactive. Like as soon as a node is being made it gets popup at the Interface.

For getting into the inside i am posting my code.

```
function recursiveGenerateTree(objNode, parntSpan, ulContainer, objEditParam) {
    var cntLi = 0;
    var spnApplyClass;
    var rdbValue;
    var cntrList = 0;

    for (cntLi = 0; cntLi <= objNode.NodeList.length - 1; cntLi++) {

            objEditParam.rdbGroup = objEditParam.rdbGroup;
            rdbValue = objEditParam.orgRootID + '_' + objNode.NodeList[cntLi].Id;
            objEditParam.rdbValue = rdbValue;
            objEditParam.selector = 'radio';
            objEditParam.selector = '';

        objEditParam.isNewNode = false;
        addChild('', parntSpan, ulContainer, objEditParam);

        $('#txtParent').val(objNode.NodeList[cntLi].Name);
        spnApplyClass = $('#txtParent').parents('span:first');
        $('#txtParent').trigger('blur', [spnApplyClass]);
        spnApplyClass.removeClass('bgLime');

        var li = spnApplyClass.parents("li:first");
        li.attr("nodeId", objNode.NodeList[cntLi].Id);
        li.attr("rootnodeId", objNode.NodeList[cntLi].RootOrgUnitId);

        var ulPrsnt = objNode.NodeList[cntLi].NodeList;
        if (ulPrsnt != undefined && ulPrsnt.length > 0) {
            recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam);
        }
    }

}
```

Second function used is Add child

```
function addChild(currentbtn, parentSpn, parentUl, objEditParam) {
    var spnElement;
    if ($(currentbtn).length > 0) {
        var dvClick = $(currentbtn).closest('div').siblings('div.OrgGroupLists')
        spnElement = $(dvClick).find('span.bgLime');
    }
    else {
        spnElement = parentSpn;
    }
    if (spnElement.length == 0 && parentUl.length == 0)
        return;

    var crtUlChild;
    if (spnElement.length > 0) {
        var dvCurrent = $(spnElement).closest("div");
        crtUlChild = $(dvCurrent).find('ul:first');
    }

    if (parentUl.length > 0) {
        crtUlChild = parentUl;
    }

    if (crtUlChild.length == 0) {
        var ulChildrens = createUl();
    }
    //Next line needs to be updated.
    var spnImage = $(dvCurrent).find("span:first");
    $(spnImage).removeClass("SpanSpace");
    $(spnImage).addClass("L7CollapseTree");
    var liChildrens = document.createElement("li");
    $(liChildrens).attr("isNew", objEditParam.isNewNode);
    $(liChildrens).attr("isTextEdited", false);
    var dvChildrens = createDivNode(objEditParam);
    $(liChildrens).append(dvChildrens);
    if (crtUlChild.length == 0) {
        $(ulChildrens).append(liChildrens);
        $(dvCurrent).append(ulChildrens);
    }
    else {
        crtUlChild.append(liChildrens);
    }



}
```

Feel free to ask any more details if required to understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: The browser uses the same thread for JavaScript as for rendering, so all of your code will execute before the page refreshes. You can refactor your loop to use `setTimeout()` and that'll let the browser refresh between each iteration.

Comment: yes I tired doing that but it didn't changed any thing in the browser behavior.

Comment: this thing work perfectly in FF but IE screw this up.

Answer (score 0):

What @nnnnnn means is that you call subsequent recursion in setTimeout.
I did not spend time trying to replicate your code locally. Check out JavaScript code below for example. setTimeout works fine for the code below. You can vary variable j's length according to your browser. The inner loop j is to block JS thread.

```
<html><head>
  <script>
  var k = 0;
  function recursiveTree(){
    $("#holder").append("<div>Item</div>");
    for(var j =0; j < 100000000; j++){
      // blocking thread
    }
    if (k++ < 20) {
      console.log(k);
      setTimeout(function(){recursiveTree()},10);
    }
  }</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id='holder'></div></body>
</html>
```

I assumed that you are using JQuery.

Just to confirm you need to make recursive call as following

```
if (ulPrsnt != undefined && ulPrsnt.length > 0) {
  setTimeout(function(){recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam);},10);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that.  setTimeout(function () { recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam)}, 100);; it didn't produced result as expected.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Just to confirm you need to make recursive call as following 
   
    if (ulPrsnt != undefined && ulPrsnt.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(function(){recursiveGenerateTree(objNode.NodeList[cntLi], spnApplyClass, '', objEditParam);},10);
    }